# Loading only part of a bitmap file in Android

Tags: android, performance, graphics

I would like to load a cropped version of a bitmap image into a Bitmap object, without loading the original bitmap as well.

Is this at all possible without writing custom loading routines to handle the raw data?

Thanks,
Sandor

Answer (score 13):

It's actually very straightforward to do. Use

`Bitmap yourBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, x to start from, y to start from, width, height)`

Update: use [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html)

Comment: Thanks Steve, but that would require me to load in the sourceBitmap first, and I am trying to avoid doing that, since it is too large to fit in memory, and I want to work with a bitmap that has not been downsampled.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I didn't read that part of your question properly. I'm not sure then how to do this without downsampling. In fact a very similar problem is on my own figure-out-how-to-do list as well!

Answer (score 10):

try this

```
InputStream istream =   null;
try {
     istream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(yourBitmapUri);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
}

BitmapRegionDecoder decoder     =   null;
try {
    decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(istream, false);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap bMap = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(istream, x to start from, y to start from, x to end with, y to end with), null);    
imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Comment: oops..sorry.. one more thing this method is intented for sdk version 2.3 or above...

Answer (score 0):

@RKN

Your method can also throw OutOfMemoryError exception - if cropped bitmap exceeds VM.

My method combines Yours and protection against this exeption:
(l, t, r, b - % of image)

```
    Bitmap cropBitmap(ContentResolver cr, String file, float l, float t, float r, float b)
{
    try 
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
        int oWidth = options.outWidth;
        int oHeight = options.outHeight;

        InputStream istream = cr.openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(new File(file)));

        BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(istream, false);
        if (decoder != null)
        {
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            int startingSize = 1;
            if ((r - l) * oWidth * (b - t) * oHeight > 2073600)
                startingSize = (int) ((r - l) * oWidth * (b - t) * oHeight / 2073600) + 1;

            for (options.inSampleSize = startingSize; options.inSampleSize <= 32; options.inSampleSize++)
            {
                try
                {
                    return decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect((int) (l * oWidth), (int) (t * oHeight), (int) (r * oWidth), (int) (b * oHeight)), options);    
                }
                catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
                {
                    Continue with for loop if OutOfMemoryError occurs
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

and returns max available bitmap or null

Comment: What if `startingSize` > 32 initially because the input image is so big?

Answer (score 0):

Use [RapidDecoder](https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder).

And simply do this

```
import rapid.decoder.BitmapDecoder;

Rect bounds = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapDecoder.from(getResources(), R.drawable.image)
        .region(bounds).decode();
```

It requires Android 2.2 or above.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the scaled version of bitmap with out fully loading the bitmap using following algorithm

- Calculate the maximum possible inSampleSize that still yields an
  image larger than your target.
- Load the image using
  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options), passing inSampleSize as an
  option.
- Resize to the desired dimensions using
  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap().

Check the following post
[Android: Resize a large bitmap file to scaled output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file) for further details.