# How to resize a bitmap image : Android

Tags: android

I want to increase size of image. i get image with this code `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.car);`

But this image has different size on different screens, so i want to resize image according to screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using the following code snippets, the first section retrns the width and height of the current screen, the second section re-sizes the image.

```
// This will return the screen size in pixels
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

// Use this to bind and re-size the image
Bitmap car;
car = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.car);
car = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(car, width, height, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can scale:

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, dstWidth, dstHeight, filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In android, one should store each resources in at least 3 formats, xhdpi, hdpi and mdpi 
considering that you have stored a resource's copy in all the 3 formats at their respective folders.

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density

The platform is enough smart to pick up right resources according to right screen size on its own.

I don't think you'll face any issues, if you have proper images in all 3 folders.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: But my question is can i scale bitmap image or not?

Comment: yes off course, and if you just want to scale use bitmap factory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360976/android-how-to-scale-an-image-with-bitmapfactory-options

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://square.github.io/picasso/ you can download, set where you want the image and resize it, just in one line. It also allows disk caching.