# Zoom, crop and save photo

Tags: android, image, zooming, crop

I want to take a photo, zoom it, crop it, and save it to the file system. For zoom I use TouchImageView (extends ImageView) from [How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images) but I could not understand how to get a bitmap after zooming. I tried getDrawable() and getDrawingCache() but they return full image, not cropped.

Comment: its spelt "photo". It would definitely help search results. All the touchimageview lets you do is zoom into it. The underlying image is left intact, full resolution. Look into "resizing" photos rather than "zoom".

Comment: Take a look at the following post for your answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file