# Size of bitmap returned by camera via intent?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, camera

How do I get a bitmap with a certain (memory friendly) size from the camera?

I'm starting a camera intent with:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

photoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mytmpimg.jpg"));
cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);        

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

I handle the result here:

```
//  Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

Bitmap photo = getBitmap(photoUri);
```

Now if I use the commented line - get the bitmap directly, I get always a 160 x 120 bitmap, and that's too small. If I load it from the URI using some standard stuff I found (method getBitmap), it loads a 2560 x 1920 bitmap (!) and that consumes almost 20 mb memory.

How do I load let's say 480 x 800 (the same size the camera preview shows me)?

Without having to load the 2560 x 1920 into memory and scaling down.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file

Comment: Probably, but isn't there a way to just get what I see on the screen when taking the pic...? I don't need anything more.

Comment: Ben Rujil's link points to the best answer I know.  Your choice is basically either thumbnail in Intent, or native-resolution photo in File.  Absent getting the camera app to save the photo at a lower resolution, that is your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, based on a method called getBitmap() from a crop library which was removed from old Android version. I did some modifications:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(Uri uri, int width, int height) {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = Math.max(width, height);
        in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
        in.close();

        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        //adjust sample size such that the image is bigger than the result
        scale -= 1;

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
        in.close();

        //scale bitmap to desired size
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);

        //free memory
        b.recycle();

        return scaledBitmap;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

What this does is load the bitmap using BitmapFactory.Options() + some sample size - this way the original image is not loaded into memory. The problem is that the sample size just works in steps. I get the "min" sample size for my image using some maths I copied - and subtract 1 in order to get the sample size which will produce the min. bitmap bigger than the size I need.

And then in order to get the bitmap with exactly the size requested do normal scaling with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);`. And immediatly after it recycle the bigger bitmap. This is important, because, for example, in my case, in order to get 480 x 800 bitmap, the bigger bitmap was 1280 x 960 and that occupies 4.6mb memory.

A more memory friendly way would be to not adjust `scale`, so a smaller bitmap will be scaled up to match the required size. But this will reduce the quality of the image.