# setImageUri on ImageView doesnt work

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to make a picture with my app but it doesn't work.

I'm implementing a function to record a picture with my app, the result of this is a URI.

This URI I have in my activity, with this I try to show the user the recorded picture, to realize this I use from the imageview the method setImageUri ... but it doesn't work for me.

The thing I'm confused about, the imageview exist, in the screen I see the dimension.

In this case, the code that I have implemented

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(activityContext);
        imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(captureImg.toString()));
        mainFrame.addView(imgView, 100, 100);
```

another solutions:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(captureImg.toString());
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(activityContext);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(d);
        mainFrame.addView(imgView, 100, 100);
```

This both doesn't work for me, I have to try to use any solutions with Bitmap but this doesn't work me too.

Greets

Comment: ok now i solved the problem with the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure your "UI code" (imgView.setImageDrawable(d);) run on UIthread
Take this for reference: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Try as:

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(activityContext);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                          (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
imgView.setLayoutParams(vp);
imgView.setMaxHeight(100);
imgView.setMaxWidth(100);
imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(captureImg.toString()));
mainFrame.addView(imgView);
```

you are not adding `LayoutParams` to dynamically created ImageView

Answer (score 0):

---Try this---

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(activityContext);
imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(captureImg.toString()));
mainFrame.addView(imgView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200));
```