# VM won't let us allocate ** bytes

Tags: android, memory, logcat, allocation, android-logcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

My app wants to allocate 2529792 bytes, I run it on device with 128mb Ram and it works fine , then I run ir on htc with 292mb of free memory of Ram and it gives error

01-14 21:08:27.972: E/GraphicsJNI(26585): VM won't let us allocate 2529792 bytes

here is my LogCat output

```
01-14 21:08:27.391: E/dalvikvm-heap(26585): 2529792-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-14 21:08:27.411: E/dalvikvm(26585): Out of memory: Heap Size=17735KB, Allocated=14425KB, Bitmap Size=14641KB, Limit=32768KB
01-14 21:08:27.411: E/dalvikvm(26585): Trim info: Footprint=17735KB, Allowed Footprint=17735KB, Trimmed=668KB
01-14 21:08:27.512: E/GraphicsJNI(26585): VM won't let us allocate 2529792 bytes
01-14 21:08:27.512: D/dalvikvm(26585): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 905K, 24% free 13520K/17735K, external 14641K/16689K, paused 93ms
01-14 21:08:27.652: D/dalvikvm(26585): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3K, 24% free 13552K/17735K, external 14641K/16689K, paused 116ms
01-14 21:08:27.662: D/skia(26585): --- decoder->decode returned false
01-14 21:08:27.792: D/dalvikvm(26585): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 13K, 24% free 13655K/17735K, external 14641K/16689K, paused 109ms
01-14 21:08:27.872: E/dalvikvm-heap(26585): 2529792-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-14 21:08:27.872: E/dalvikvm(26585): Out of memory: Heap Size=17735KB, Allocated=13655KB, Bitmap Size=14641KB, Limit=32768KB
01-14 21:08:27.872: E/dalvikvm(26585): Trim info: Footprint=17735KB, Allowed Footprint=17735KB, Trimmed=1408KB
01-14 21:08:27.972: E/GraphicsJNI(26585): VM won't let us allocate 2529792 bytes
01-14 21:08:27.972: D/dalvikvm(26585): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 39K, 24% free 13615K/17735K, external 14641K/16689K, paused 96ms
01-14 21:08:28.092: D/dalvikvm(26585): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 40K, 24% free 13579K/17735K, external 14641K/16689K, paused 102ms
01-14 21:08:28.212: D/dalvikvm(26585): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 41K, 24% free 13574K/17735K, external 14641K/16689K, paused 103ms
01-14 21:08:28.212: W/dalvikvm(26585): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
01-14 21:08:28.252: E/dalvikvm-heap(26585): 2529792-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-14 21:08:28.252: E/dalvikvm(26585): Out of memory: Heap Size=17735KB, Allocated=13585KB, Bitmap Size=13902KB, Limit=32768KB
01-14 21:08:28.252: E/dalvikvm(26585): Trim info: Footprint=17735KB, Allowed Footprint=17735KB, Trimmed=1468KB
01-14 21:08:28.352: E/GraphicsJNI(26585): VM won't let us allocate 2529792 bytes
```

Can anybody help me ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `android:largeHeap="true"` in the `Manifest.xml`? I can also see that you are dealing with bitmap, use BitMapOptions like this method:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
InputStream in = null;
try {
    final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
    in.close();



    int scale = 1;
    while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > 
          IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
       scale++;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", 
       orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

    Bitmap b = null;
    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
    if (scale > 1) {
        scale--;
        // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
        // larger than target
        o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inSampleSize = scale;
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

        // resize to desired dimensions
        int height = b.getHeight();
        int width = b.getWidth();
        Log.d(TAG, "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ",
           height: " + height);

        double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                / (((double) width) / height));
        double x = (y / height) * width;

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x, 
           (int) y, true);
        b.recycle();
        b = scaledBitmap;

        System.gc();
    } else {
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    }
    in.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "bitmap size - width: " +b.getWidth() + ", height: " + 
       b.getHeight());
    return b;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
    return null;
}
```

Source: [Android: Resize a large bitmap file to scaled output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file)

Comment: Thank you very much , but I didn't use any bitmap, and the HTC was more powerful than first one. I think there are some options or something like that , I don't know exactly, and I also want to allocate only 2-3 mb , I don't think that there must be a problem with Ram memory