# resize image on android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I want to change the size of an image taken by the camera say 600x800. I am successfully doing so and its working fine but I also want to change the byte size or you can say memory as well. Like the photo resizer app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xllusion.app.photoresizer&feature=search_result on google play. For example if I take a photo on this app and change the resolution to 600x800. It creating this resolution photo simply with 23kb(no quality compromise) where as original photo was of 600kb. Can somebody help???

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried?

Comment: @Numair resizedBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, (int)scale_width, (int)scale_height, true); .It changing the resolution but not byte size like I want.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file will help you.