# Android-app crash on adding image in custom list view

Tags: android, android-listview, camera, out-of-memory

i am making **custom list view** in which i have to add images taken by user either from sd card or by camera.For this i take one image view and two buttons.one button take picture from **camera** and other from **sd card** and then they add picture in image view..Now when i pass that image uri in custom list view then for the first time image is added but second time application crashes....if someone knows the answer then plz post it.
thanks in advance!!

here is the code.
This is for button click..

```
camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg")));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            }
        });

        sdcard.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, 0);

            }
        });

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                list12,
                R.layout.list_row_1,
                new String[] { "name", "address", "location", "image" },
                new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.address, R.id.location, R.id.image });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

After this..

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 2) {
            File picture = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/temp.jpg");

            imgUri = Uri.fromFile(picture);
            targetImage.setImageURI(imgUri);
            location1 = "Camera";
        }

        else {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                targetUri = data.getData();
                textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                            .openInputStream(targetUri));

                    //decodeBitmap(bitmap, 4, 4);

                    targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    location1 = "Sd card";

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

and then i m adding image in list View

```
private void populateList() {

    HashMap<String, Object> temp11 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    name1 = textname.getText().toString();
    address1 = textaddress.getText().toString();


    if (name1.equals("") || address1.equals("")) {
        String str = "Don't Leave field blank !";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LastPage.this,

        str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    else if (location1 == "Sd card") {

        textname.setText("");
        textaddress.setText("");
        temp11.put("name", name1);
        temp11.put("address", address1);

        temp11.put("location", location1);

        temp11.put("image", targetUri);
        targetImage.setImageBitmap(null);
        list12.add(0, temp11);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else if (location1 == "Camera") {

        textname.setText("");
        textaddress.setText("");
        temp11.put("name", name1);
        temp11.put("address", address1);
        temp11.put("location", location1);

        temp11.put("image", imgUri);
        targetImage.setImageBitmap(null);
        list12.add(0, temp11);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

logcat

```
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:573)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:439)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:657)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:521)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:305)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.setViewImage(SimpleAdapter.java:264)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:192)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1610)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1264)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:845)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-20 00:03:49.599: E/AndroidRuntime(4129):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 00:03:58.999: W/dalvikvm(4206): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2385: Lcom/korovyansk/android/sample/slideout/SampleActivity;.getActionBar ()Landroid/app/ActionBar;
```

Comment: edit your post and include the code that you are using, and the exception that is getting put into the logcat. Without these pieces of information there is no way we can help you.

Comment: @FoamyGuy..i hv added my code.plz hv a look

Comment: Could you add the logcat as well?

Comment: @DigCamara...thanks a lot.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather big image from the camera? Try decreasing the size of that image (reducing the resolution in the camera settings).

Looks like you are exceeding the memory you have available to your app:

From the log you posted:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

But other than that you are probably leaking some memory. You should discard (recycle) those bitmaps etc.

@DigCamara posted some excellent links in his/her answer! Really, a must read for your situation.

Comment: I suggest upvoting the answers if they helped, especially DigCamara's.

Comment: @Mattias thanks for the idea. But I think (s)he can't upvote answers yet.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)?

In particular you need to check out how to [manage memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html). Before you load your bitmap, you should try to verify what options you need to use to downscale its size, for instance.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file/8497703#8497703) might help you with the code you need to re-scale your image before you try to load it.