# Android Image read , modify and save

Tags: android, imageview, bitmapfactory

I am trying to do the following steps -

1. Read an `scaled` image from assets and display in an imageview. - `Successful`
2. Modify the image - `Successful`
3. Save it to the SD card.- `Not successful`.

The resolution of the image is `4608 x 3456` with `300 ppi`.
Since i was getting an `out of memory exception` on reading the image,
 i have scaled down the image to `800 * 800`  while reading it using `BitmapFactory.Options` .
Now when i modify and save the image to SD card , the resolution of the image is `800 * 800` .
I want to get the exact same resolution as the resolution of the image in assets.

How to achieve this ? 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file) helped me to create Image of required resolution i tried creating full hd image(1920×1080) i'm not sure whether you can create 4608 x 3456 resolution image.

Comment: The problem i am facing is i have an image of 800 * 800 in the imageview  and i want to scale it up while saving it to sd card. If i try to do it i an getting OOM .

Comment: Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,3456,4608, matrix, true); are u creting something like this ??

Comment: Yes. But i am getting OOM for this .

Comment: @Anukool with my logic i'm able to create 3264x2448 resolution image i think that is the max u can create in Android.still required u can use any Image compression algorithm(c\c++).