# How to resize a photo already taken and stored in a file?

Tags: android, bitmap, photo, image-resizing

I read about this in several forum questions. But always, people end up using the method "Bitmap createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)", but I can not apply this method because, when dealing with large images, it fails with a message of outofmemory.

I want to know how I can resize a large image already taken. I've readed the android developer section of large bitmaps but I haven't been able to implement it.

I'm using the next code to capture a photo.

```
public void openTakePicture() {

        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());

        photoname = "pic_" + date + ".jpg";

        // Create an output file.
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), photoname);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        // Generate the Intent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        // Launch the camera app.
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    }
```

Thanks for your comments

Comment: try this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file

Comment: Thank you, but this method is similar to createScaledBitmap and gives me a outofmemory error too.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you could capture a smaller picture and then manipulate it.  I was using something similar to the below but ran into issues where some cameras didn't support the setPictureSize so I ended up using the scaled bitmap approach.

You may need to test to see if the camera supports your desired size before calling setPictureSize.

```
parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
parameters.setPictureSize(1600, 1200);
parameters.setJpegQuality(30);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```