# Genymotion emulator increase heap size

Tags: android, emulation, heap-memory, genymotion

I'm trying to increase a Genymotion 2.3 emulator in order to test my app. Is there any way to accomplish this? I can't find a way to configure the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26507789/535369) post mentions how to do it. But I don't know how or what or where the root shell is to execute that command or to change those values. They are not present in the build.prop files that are in the system-images folder. Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To increase heap size in Genymotion, please do the following -

1. Open your terminal and write `adb shell`.
2. Type `su`
3. Type `mount -o remount,rw /system`
4. Type `vi /system/build.prop`
5. Change `dalvik.vm.heapsize=256m` to your liking. Here **256m** is **256mb**
6. Restart Genymotion

Comment: 1|vbox86p:/ # mount -o remount,rw /system                                      
mount: '/dev/block/sda6'->'/system': Device or resource busy

Comment: @user3562927 Using Genymotion or other Emulator ?

Comment: Genymotion.  Couldn't get it to work.  Tried restarting, using different images -- no luck.

Comment: @user3562927 What issues you are getting in Genymotion? Can you create a separate question for it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to increase the genymotion heap size. Do you mean you want to increase the size of the virtual device memory? You can do this in the virtual device settings. You can find them in the dialog where you start the devices from.

Comment: I did mean to say MEMORY HEAP SIZE no size of the virtual device memory. About the mac, it was a typo.

Comment: Genymotion is a native mac app, not java. So the OS manages the memory for it. I don't think there is anything that you can do to increase it, I don't even think that there is a memory limit. It will just start to swap it out to the disk at some point.