# Android resize photo on the fly

Tags: android

I am trying to copy a photo. Before copying it, I must check if the photo has width and height smaller than 10000 px. When it is smaller, I have to resize it to 10000px on the fly and then copy it. How can I do it without saving in memory? Are there some library?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the photograph stored? What do you mean by copyinb it? Copy the file? Why do you need to resize it BEFORE you copy it? Woudn't it be sufficient to resize the copy? Because resizing has a negative impact on the images quality. Do you really want to do that with the "original"?

Comment: Yes I have tried with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file , but I can't resize the image in the size I want. I was reading about Picassso but with it I need to save the image and I don't want to, it may be on the fly. And yes, if the image has this size I have to obligatory resize before copy it.