# Out of Memory error while running project in android studio

Tags: android, image-loading

I am getting Out of memory error while running my project. I understand this error because of large background images in the project. I came across some articles to scale down an image and then load them. How can I scale down all the images and load them efficiently in the project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Comment: Probably you can have a look into this article
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8497703/2793134

Answer (score 1):

Picasso is a great library for handling images for Android.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Loading an image for a specific size and can easy like this:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

If you are truly showing alot of images, consider setting  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="foo.bar"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the size of images change the inSampleSize of each image. If inSampleSize is set to a value > 1 then the decoder subsamples the original image and returns you a smaller image to save memory. inSampleSize can be found in BitmapFactory.Options

Go to the following link for more details on this :-

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

If your images still lags you can scale them down further by help of Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter) method.