# android resize bitmap auto height

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I try to resize bitmap from gallery.I wrote some code and i can resize bitmap only static width and height.this is source

```
     public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth) {

    float aspectRatio = (float)bm.getWidth() / (float) bm.getHeight();
    int height = Math.round(newWidth / aspectRatio); //based on width it gives height
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    matrix.postScale(newWidth, height);

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bm, 0, 0, newWidth, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

but i want to resize bitmap for example width 800px and auto height.is it a possible to solve this problem in android ?
thanks

Comment: [refer this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file) i also got solution for same problem from this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
int width = bm.getWidth();
int height = bm.getHeight();
Bitmap resizedBitmap;


try {
         resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                boolean_image = true;
                return "";

            }

return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
float aspectRatio = (float)Image.getWidth() / (float) Image.getHeight();
int width = 200;    //your width
int height = Math.round(width / aspectRatio); //based on width it gives height
```