# Out of Memory Bitmap Decode File - Android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

I have the same problem found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file) and I do not know if now there is a a solution.
I have a Bitmap image of 2592x1944 pixels and, when I run Bitmap.decodeFile(...) the application crashes cause OutOfmemory Exception.

Does anyone of you know how to solve it?

Thank you very much

Here below my code:

```
for (int iFile = 0; iFile < files.length; iFile++) {
     if (files[iFile].exists()) {
         bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[iFile].getAbsolutePath());
         int[][][] rgb = Utils.getImageRgb(bitmap);

         indexLastFile = iFile + 1;
         images.put("M" + (iFile + 1), rgb);
      }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `Bitmap` decode for big files. I remember resizing with Bitmap was really pain because of performance issues. `OutOfmemory` is a one of dark sides of that

Comment: Thanks a lot man for your time, but what should I do instead of using Bitmap.decodeFile()?

Comment: use `imageloaders` instead. I personally prefers Glide.

Comment: Could you give me an example au using this method?

Comment: you decode method for bitmap decoding and you post your code'

Comment: @MaximShoustin could you give me an example please?

Comment: I used OpenGL2, works really fast but im not sure its your case

Comment: I have a java class which take a 5MPX image from an external cam and transforms it, or it should do, in a map[width][height][3] of RGB. Cause this algorithm has to run in an Android device, a Bitmap is necessary but when I run Bitmap.decodeFile() the app crashes

Comment: To that in background thread

Comment: This that it has to be run under Android OS, are you sure it will fix the problem?

Comment: It will not help you to use imageloaders as they will prabably load a resized image. You want the full resolution if i understand you right. The app does not have to crash of course if you catch the exception or error.

Comment: Yes man, exactly this

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the bitmap alone, try to load image efficiently, You need to scale the image before even loading the image into ram memory.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12cB7gnL6po follow this video series to load bitmap efficiently.

Comment: No man. I do not want to scale image because scaling is a pixels average and I need all pixels

Comment: Can you explain why you need bitmap with no loss in pixels, so that we can provide you a better solution??

Comment: Because I have to extract RGB color for each pixel in the image, so if I scale the image, the pixels will be moved and I won't able to get the same output, so I have to maintain the same pixels

Comment: Great! But loading a bitmap fully is very bit and getting the rgb out of it is like doubling the size of bitmap in RAM, So can you explain why you need the pixel colors??

Comment: In order to extract some info putting masks and get some parameters as area, volume, depth etc. I really need pixels color

Comment: You can get the info part by part, but not entirely. So you can get part of the bitmap without scaling by calling Bitmap bitmap = BitmapRegionDecoder.decodeRegion(rect, null);, rect defines the bounds of the image you want to load. From example if you have 400x400 image, just load 100x100 part of the image and extract info and store it in disk or db. Now clear the variable and load next 100x100 part of the image to extract info. You cannot load the entire bitmap or you cannot have the entire bitmap pixel RGB in your app memory(RAM).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139980/discussion-between-paride-letizia-and-sujith-niraikulathan).

Comment: Not see the conversation

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid playing with bitmaps otherwise you have to face OutOfMemory exceptions.

Try image libraries [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to avoid out of memory issues & better performance.

Replace path with local folder path or server url

```
Glide.with (context).load (path).asBitmap().into(imageView);
```

Comment: How does this help? Be specific (Bitmap.Config, target size, etc.)

Comment: Can you post your code so that I can update it in the way you need it

Comment: @Pehlaj please post your code how to decode a file without to put it in a imageView

Comment: ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filesPath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE))Why do you need to decode file to bitmap?

Comment: @Pehlaj I have a java class which take a 5MPX image from an external cam and transforms it, or it should do, in a map[width][height][3] of RGB. Cause this algorithm has to run in an Android device, a Bitmap is necessary but when I run Bitmap.decodeFile() the app crashes

Comment: You should avoid playing with bitmaps otherwise you have to face OutOfMemory exceptions.

Comment: @Pehlaj sure. You can find it above. Could you give me your email so I can write down my full issue?