# Can't use Android.Graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder with Xamarin

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin to build an Android app in c#.

The problem I'm having is that I need to load a part of an image without loading the whole image first. I have a rectangle of the region I want from the image.
I found this solution for normal Android : [BitmapRegionDecoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546193/loading-only-part-of-a-bitmap-file-in-android)

However when I try to invoke this class in my Xamarin project it's not there and I can't import it either.
I looked in the API and it says that it should be there.[Android.Graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder documentation](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M:Android.Graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder.DecodeRegion%28Android.Graphics.Rect,Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory%2bOptions%29)

Does anyone know if it's possible to use this class or if there is another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it says it is present in API level 10, hence you have to set your minimum target to 10 in the Application properties.

Then you can use it like so:

```
using (var inStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("YourBitmapUri")))
{
    using (var decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.NewInstance(inStream, false))
    {
        var bitmap = decoder.DecodeRegion(YourRect, new BitmapFactory.Options());
        // use your bitmap i.e. for an ImageView
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured that it was enough that i set the targetsdk to 10 in my android manifest. However I had to go to the properties of my app and set Minimum Android to target to 10.