# Android Display Large Bitmaps from disk ImageFetcher OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have an implementation like the one that's in this tutorial -> http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

The problem: ImageFetcher class downloads the image from web, and I have my images on disk.

Debugging the code, I realized that the Bitmap returning method is:

`private Bitmap processBitmap(String data);`

What can I do?, my images sizes are about 1920x1080, and I need to display them full-screen. Its an Android 22" all-in-one.

I always get OOM error..
That's why I'm trying with the android tutorial code, but I don't know how to generate the bitmap from disk in that resolution without getting the error.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion use Canvas and draw your Bitmap by parts. You can save parts of image on disk and load it one by one. Another solution read parts of big bitmap. [Here is the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546193/loading-only-part-of-a-bitmap-file-in-android)

Comment: So you mean that If I load my bitmap by parts, and show it cropped in four parts for example, I'll avoid OOM?
How can I do that?, I'm using a ViewPager (the same implementation that is showed in Android's BitmapForFun example).

Comment: The problem is that your bit map 1920*1080 need almost 2*4=8 Mbyte in memory, I you load your image very fast and GC have no time to free this memory you will get OOM. Show me please part of code where you set your image.